# Doubt on subspace of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

I am new to linear algebra and I have a doubt that : in 2D coordinate system is a line which is at 45 degree **NOT** passing through the origin a subspace of the vector space comprising the whole 2D plane i.e. $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ ? 
let $V = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2  \}$. and $W = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y-x+1=0 \}$ so is $W$ a subspace of $V$...please correct me if my expressions to express vector spaces/sub spaces are wrong...thank you

Comment: Thanx guys for clearing my doubt...a +1 to all coz I cant accept ony one's answer as correct as all are correct...

Answer (score 2):

No, subspaces alway contain the null vector, since if they contain $(x,y)$, they contain $(ax,ay)$ for any real $a$, including $a=0$.

Answer (score 1):

A subspace $S$ of a vector space must always contain the zero vector, because (it is not allowed to be the empty set, and) (i) it must be closed under subtraction: if $x\in S$ then $x-x=\vec 0\in S$, or alternatively (ii) it must be closed under scalar multiplication if $x\in S$ then $0x=\vec 0\in S$.

Answer (score 1):

Your $W$ is not a **linear subspace**, which is what we mean when we say "subspace" in a linear algebra course.  But $W$ is an **affine subspace**, a term used in mathematics as well.

Comment: Can I know some few words about affine subspace?or if you give me some reference...I have gone through wiki and couldnt get the phrase "affine properties of euclidian space"

Comment: @rotat: Maybe search here, and not general Google... for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185768/ ... A nice textbook on geometry (including affine geometry) is Coxeter *Introduction to Geometry*.